# Unable to build ODL sdn controller code .?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I have downloaded the code using

```
git clone https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/p/integration/distribution.git
```

When I try to build this, it shows following error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.integration:root:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 11
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.opendaylight.integration:root:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/controller/distribution/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.integration:root:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [make sure your `settings.xml` points to the OpenDaylight Nexus artifact repository](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup#Edit_your_.7E.2F.m2.2Fsettings.xml). The simplest way to do this is to download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml and place it in your `~/.m2` folder (wherever that is — it depends on your operating system).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your settings.xml should be updated. An alternative way of updating (though same result as above):

Run this from your terminal:
`cp -n ~/.m2/settings.xml{,.orig} ; \wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml > ~/.m2/settings.xml`

As suggested by stephen, path may be different based on your OS. Change it accordingly.